# Simulating a train with threads

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

Edit : I think i'm making somthing wrong because when I compile and run my binary twice, I get differents outputs..

I'm trying to understand threads with `pthread` so I did a little code to simulate the passage of a train on a bridge (who can handle only 2 train at a time)

I managed to do it for only one train to cross the bridge at a time with a code like this :

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

pthread_mutex_t mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;

void    *train()
{
  int   km;
  static int    t = 0;

  km = 1;
  while (km != 10)
    {
      printf("I'm at %02d km\n", km++);
      sleep(1);
      if (km == 2)
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
      if (km == 4)
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
    }
}

int     main()
{
  pthread_t     train1;
  pthread_t     train2;
  pthread_t     train3;

  pthread_create(&train1, NULL, train, NULL);
  pthread_create(&train2, NULL, train, NULL);
  pthread_create(&train3, NULL, train, NULL);

  pthread_join(train1, NULL);
  pthread_join(train2, NULL);
  pthread_join(train3, NULL);
}
```

This one worked perfectly (Or maybe did I do something wrong, if so please tell me)

And then I tried for the case when 2 train can pass on the bridge at the same time.

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

pthread_mutex_t mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;

void    *train()
{
  int   km;
  static int    t = 0;

  km = 1;
  while (km != 30)
    {
      printf("I'm at %02d km\n", km++);
      sleep(1);
      if (km == 2 && t <= 2)
        {
          ++t;
          pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
        }
      if (km == 4)
        {
          t--;
          pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
        }
    }
}

int     main()
{
  pthread_t     train1;
  pthread_t     train2;
  pthread_t     train3;
  pthread_t     train4;

  pthread_create(&train1, NULL, train, NULL);
  pthread_create(&train2, NULL, train, NULL);
  pthread_create(&train3, NULL, train, NULL);
  pthread_create(&train4, NULL, train, NULL);

  pthread_join(train1, NULL);
  pthread_join(train2, NULL);
  pthread_join(train3, NULL);
  pthread_join(train4, NULL);
}
```

So I used a static int to "cap" my train to 2 on the bridge but that don't really work and I don't see why..

My 4 train are strating, then 2 go on the train, the 2 others wait, when the 2 firsts leave the bridge, only one more go on it and the last wait 'till the 3rd one leave the bridge to go..

Actually, I'd like to have the 4 train to go, 2 go on the bridge, 2 waits and when the 2 firsts leave the bridge the 2 other go on the bridge.

I'm sorry it's a bit long, but needed for understanding I guess.

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem with your code is that all `pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);` does is wait until `mutex` is no longer locked, and then locks it. It doesn't actually check what the value of `t` is.

What you're really looking for is a *condition variable*:

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

pthread_mutex_t mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
pthread_cond_t cond = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;

void    *train()
{
    int   km;
    static int t = 0;

    km = 1;
    while (km != 30)
    {
        printf("I'm at %02d km\n", km);

        // If we've reached the bridge, wait until less than two trains are on it.
        if (km == 2)
        {
            pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
            while (t == 2) { // To be read as: "While two trains are on the bridge, wait."
                pthread_cond_wait(&cond, &mutex);
            }
            ++t; // Put this train onto the bridge.
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
        }

        // Leave the bridge.
        if (km == 4)
        {
            pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
            --t; // Take this train off the bridge.
            pthread_cond_signal(&cond); // Signal another train to enter.
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
        }

        // Move forward 1 km.
        sleep(1);
        ++km;
    }
}

int     main()
{
    pthread_t     train1;
    pthread_t     train2;
    pthread_t     train3;
    pthread_t     train4;

    pthread_create(&train1, NULL, train, NULL);
    pthread_create(&train2, NULL, train, NULL);
    pthread_create(&train3, NULL, train, NULL);
    pthread_create(&train4, NULL, train, NULL);

    pthread_join(train1, NULL);
    pthread_join(train2, NULL);
    pthread_join(train3, NULL);
    pthread_join(train4, NULL);
}
```

The point of the extra lock and unlock in the `if (km == 4)` bit is to make sure that there aren't multiple threads trying to change/check for the value of `t` at once. (multiple threads accessing the same variable at once usually results in very buggy behaviour!)

Comment: Oh okay, thanks for the answer, was a little lost with all that but you just clarified all I wanted, thanks a lot again !

Answer (score 0):

`static int t` is a global variable accessed and modified by different threads without a proper locking mechanism: all trains may assume they are alone and only a single one will be able to lock the mutex at a time.

Comment: That's what I intended, as it is accessible by all threads the `if (km == 2 && t <= 2)` condition should stop the others no ?

Comment: @nookonee: The point is that the threads are all (potentially) running at the same time - so if all 3 check the value of `t` at once, they'll all see that it's `0`, and so all cross the bridge at once. You need to have a way to make sure that only one thread can be manipulating the value of `t` at a time...

Comment: @psmears: they all *try* to cross the bridge at once, all four increment t (undefined behaviour) and only one of them gets the mutex while the other three wait to get it.  Indeed they will cross the bridge one at a time. This is one possible scenario, others are possible too.

Comment: @chqrlie: Oops, once I saw that `t` was being read and modified at the same time, I stopped reading the code too closely! But it is still theoretically possible for all four to cross the bridge at once: the first thread finds `t==0` and so increments `t`; at the same time all the other threads read `t` - undefined behaviour, so could get value 100 - in which case they'll skip even trying to get the mutex...